# Parallax Background Image Slightly to the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, parallax.js

I am using stellar.js to create a parallax effect on my webpage. The problem is that the background image is slightly to the left. Here is the js code I'm using:

```
function() {
    if ( !isMobile.any()) {
        $(window).stellar();
    }
};
```

For some reason it doesnt seem to work. It puts the image 25 px to the left leaving some of the background color showing.

Comment: It is really hard to help you with this info. It is probably an padding or margin on the body that is causing this issue. But no way to tell with only the info you provided

Comment: @Merijindk when I change data-stellar-background-ratio equal to 1 it fixes the problem but the parallax scrolling effect no longer works.